# How to get the error if GDALOpenEx fails?

Tags: gdal, error, c++

I am using GDAL 2.1.0 in a C++ application.

I call `GDALOpenEx()` to open a dataset file.  If it fails to open the file, it returns NULL.  That is sufficient to bail early.  But, I would also like to know what the error was that caused it to fail.

The documentation for `GDALOpenEx()` ( https://gdal.org/api/raster_c_api.html#gdal_8h_1a9cb8585d0b3c16726b08e25bcc94274a ) says:

> If all drivers fail then NULL is returned and an error is issued.

"an error is issued" probably means that it is sent to the callback I register with `CPLSetErrorHandler()`.  I already have such a callback so that the error is logged to my log file.
However, is there another way I can get the error immediately after I call `GDALOpenEx()` ?